# How to store offline Storage permanent data inside browser in Progressive Web Apps?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

Is it Possible to store permanent data in offline Storage inside browser? 
If any solution is there then help me so that i can solve my problem.
I read Some Tutorial but that is not useful me .
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: what kind of solution offered by the tutorial that you've read ?

Comment: Durable storage inside this using persistent storage for PWAs .

Comment: this is the link https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/web-storage/offline-for-pwa

Answer (score 4):

Let’s get right to the point with a general recommendation for storing data offline:

- For the network resources necessary to load your app while offline, use the Cache API (part of service workers).
- For all other data, use IndexedDB (with a promises wrapper).

I'll tell you how to use both after i tell you the storage limits per browser.

- Chrome supports use of <6% of free space
- Firefox supports use of <10% of free space
- Safari supports use of <50MB
- Internet Explorer 10 supports use of <250MB
- With Edge it depends on [volume size](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/storage/IndexedDB/)

A working example of a service worker using the cache api is

```
var CACHE_VERSION = 1;

// Shorthand identifier mapped to specific versioned cache.
var CURRENT_CACHES = {
  font: 'font-cache-v' + CACHE_VERSION
};

self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  var expectedCacheNames = Object.values(CURRENT_CACHES);

  // Active worker won't be treated as activated until promise
  // resolves successfully.
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.map(function(cacheName) {
          if (!expectedCacheNames.includes(cacheName)) {
            console.log('Deleting out of date cache:', cacheName);

            return caches.delete(cacheName);
          }
        })
      );
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  console.log('Handling fetch event for', event.request.url);

  event.respondWith(

    // Opens Cache objects that start with 'font'.
    caches.open(CURRENT_CACHES['font']).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function(response) {
        if (response) {
          console.log('Found response in cache:', response);

          return response;
        }

        console.log('Fetching request from the network');

        return fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
          cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());

          return networkResponse;
        });
      }).catch(function(error) {

        // Handles exceptions that arise from match() or fetch().
        console.error('Error in fetch handler:', error);

        throw error;
      });
    })
  );
});
```

[[Source and Explanation]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache)

And i'm not sure about how to use IndexedDB
Some other ways are

- The File System API which is only for Chrome  13+, Edge, Firefox 50+ and Opera 15+  [[Tutorial]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystem)
- Web Storage (e.g LocalStorage and SessionStorage) is synchronous, has no Web Worker support and is size and type (strings only) limited. [[Tutorial]](https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/)
- There are other but those aren't widely supported and are very difficult